# Postgres trigger functions to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, t-sql, database-migration

I wrote triggers using postgres and now I need to put all of them in sql server but I don't know how to do it. I have this triggers here:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER "InsereDependente"
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON func_dep FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertDep();



  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertDep()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $insertDep$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (select * from funcionario where cpf = NEW.func_cpf AND nome = NEW.func_nome) then
        insert into dependente values(NEW.func_cpf, NEW.dep_nome, NEW.dep_gen, NEW.dep_data_nasc, NEW.relacionamento);
    ELSE
        Raise Exception 'O funcionario não está cadastrado no banco.';
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;

$insertDep$ 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 1;
ALTER FUNCTION insertDep()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Is there anyone here who knows how can I migrate this functions to SQL Server? I have more functions to migrate I just add one of them here, to see if someone could help me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is not a code writing service. Your triggers are going to require manual effort. Keep in mind that triggers in sql server do NOT fire once per row, they fire once per operation. And there is no FOR EACH ROW. You want to use set based logic and not RBAR logic.

Comment: What specific aspect do you need help with? This isn't a code-writing service, so a good question and answer here would be one that gives you the general knowledge you need to translate all / most of your triggers without raising one question for each. This site is also not a substitute for reading the official documentation, so have you at least looked up some basic examples of SQL Server triggers?

Comment: Thank you for answering. The main problem for me is here:  CREATE TRIGGER "InsereDependente"
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON func_dep FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertDep(); I read the documentation and it seems in sql server it´s not separated as we do in postgres. I don´t know how to join the process of create trigger and create function. That´s my doubt.